# How do i use android library as module that i create in my project app?

Tags: android

I am looking a way to separated my code for app i am creating. This is just experimenter, and i am not sure if i it's good thing

My project structure looks like this

> | --app
>
> |
>
> |--login

In my login android library, i have Login screen with just two input field nothing special.

So, how do i use this, in my app project?

Do i need to publish it to use it as url? Or i can use it internally?

settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':login'
```

login librabry
build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
}
```

and app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.mandala"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
implementation project(':login')
}
```

And i can't seems to include login library/module in my app inside layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your library build.gradle replace the line:

`implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

with

`api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

In your app build.gradle, remove the line:

`implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

in your layout xml you may have to include the full package name, for example `<com.domain.project.CustomLoginView>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I'm doing the same like you but I'm setting library module as the below. Try to add `path:` to your build.gradle. BTW if you want to make your library open, you can upload it to remote repository for sharing. But If you don't, you can only use it on your project.

```
implementation project(path: ':login')
```